# Accessing environment variables in non widget classes in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have implemented environment variables based on build environment(Production/Development). The environment config is passed down the widget tree as an InheritedWidget. I am able to access these environment variables down the tree. (Referring this article - https://cogitas.net/creating-flavors-of-a-flutter-app/ )

However I have also created an API helper class which makes API calls. I want to access one of the environment variables(BASE_URL) in that class. 
Since this class is not part of widget tree I am not able to access it.

How to access these environment variables in the non widget class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: Wrap your API helper into a Widget.

You can create a custom StatefulWidget that instantiate your API helper by passing your "environment" as parameter. And then expose that helper using the widget context. Maybe by using InheritedWidget if that makes sense, or potentially just by using `context.ancestorStateOfType`

Comment: Thanks. I am also using the same approach.